# Память исчезла в никуда

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я решил переустановить Linux на VirtualBox, выделил ~60 гб динамической памяти. Все запустилось, обновления загрузились, потом мне пишет - память заполнена. То есть там вообще ничего нет, куда эта память делась, объясните?

Comment: Ну просто посмотрите любым файловым менеджером, что заняло память?

Comment: `ncdu`, `baobab`.

Comment: А Linux то знает что вы ей выделяете динамическую память?